# Spring test initialize database from code

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-data-jpa

I'm looking for the way to initialize my test h2 database with some initial test data from java code for the future tests. But I don't wanna use `@Before` annotation, because this data will be used in all test cases in all classes. I already found how to do this using SQL files with initial data. But I don't wanna write SQL inserts. It's easier for me to write some java code and then save created objects to the database. Is it possible to do? If yes, show me please how to do that.

As I didn't found answer to my question, it might be a bad idea at all. If yes, explain me why, please?

In my project I'm using Spring data JPA. I'm new with spring integrational testing and only start to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my current project I used DbUnit. You can define an xml with the status of the DB at the beginning and after the test.
You can give it a look here.

[https://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/](http://Spring%20Test%20DbUnit)

You can configure it to use H2 Driver in the application.properties:

```
dbunit.datasource.h2.drivername=org.h2.Driver
dbunit.datasource.h2.url=jdbc:h2:mem:unit-testing-jpa;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;
dbunit.datasource.h2.username=user
dbunit.datasource.h2.password=pwd
```

The test will be like:

```
@Test
@DatabaseSetup(value = "InitialDataset.xml")
@ExpectedDatabase(value = "ExpectedDataset.xml", assertionMode = DatabaseAssertionMode.NON_STRICT)
public void test() throws IOException, UnhandledRequestException {
    ...
}
```

An example of a dataset would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataset>
    <user id="1" first_name="john" family_name="doe" />
    <user id="100" first_name="jane" family_name="doe"/>
</dataset>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `Datasource`, I suggest you intialize your database for unit testing this way :

From [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc-initializing-datasource-xml) :

> **Initializing a database using Spring XML**
>
> If you want to initialize a database and you can provide a reference
>   to a DataSource bean, use the initialize-database tag in the
>   spring-jdbc namespace:
>
> ```
> <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
>         <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/foo/sql/db-schema.sql"/>
>         <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/foo/sql/db-test-data.sql"/>
> </jdbc:initialize-database>
> ```

**Explanation**

In your Spring configuration for unit tests, I'm assuming you defined a specific `datasource`. In this case, you can initialize this database with SQL scripts available only for unit testing.